# Sticky tag doesn't change headings

Tags: css, sticky, heading

I would like to do a sticky headings. Where one heading get stick by CSS sticky element when it is in touch with top of the page. And when come the another heading it should push away the old one and instead there are stuck both of them.

[code](https://jsfiddle.net/Venous/yyws4qes/)

```
<h1>HEADING</h1><br />
<h2>Heading</h2>
<p>text</p>
<h2>Another heading</h2>
<p>text</p>
```

```css
h2 {
    font-size: 40px;   
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 120px; 
    margin-bottom: 80px; 
    padding: 15px;   
    position: sticky; 
    top: -1px; 
}              
p {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px; 
    margin-bottom: 80px; 
    color: #262216;
}   
h2,p {
    display: flex;
    min-width: 500px;
    max-width: 1000px;    
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that `position: sticky` is an *experimental API* and shouldn't be used in production yet? (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky) It's not fully integrated and supported by all browsers. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Browser_compatibility for browser compatibility and support.)

Comment: Okey than, is there any other option without js to do it this way?

Comment: No way to achieve the same intended behaviour without javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the first header to be pushed out of the window by the second header, put the header and the content after it up to the next header in a separate container. `sticky` works only in containers that are visible on the screen, so as soon as the container is out of view, the h2 is no longer sticky.
In this example, I used a `section` for a container.

Note that the huge bottom margin on the p makes what happens difficult to follow, but if you change that to bottom padding, it will make the effect much clearer.

```css
  h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 120px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  color: #262216;
}

h2,
p {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
```

```html
<h1>HEADING</h1>
<section>
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <p>text <br/>
     text <br/>
     text <br/>
     text <br/>
     text <br/>
     text <br/>
     text <br/>
     text <br/>
     text <br/>
     text <br/>
     text <br/>
     text <br/>
     text <br/>
     text <br/>
     text <br/>
     text <br/>
     text <br/>
     text <br/>
     text </p>
</section>
<section>
  <h2>Another heading</h2>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
</section>
```

Also, `sticky` currently doesn't work in IE, so if you need to support IE, you'll have to find a different solution, like the comments say.